# Insert p_key of row inserted in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table containing client data, their main address data and their work address data, this needs to be split into 2 tables **clients** and **addresses**.

Client has columns "address1" and "address2" which are supposed to be the primary keys of the corresponding addresses in the **addresses** table, but addresses can't have a column for client p_keys.

My question is: how can I properly get the pkeys of the new addresses in the client table?

Example of what I would want to achieve:

```
insert into clients
(
    _name, 
    _address1,
    _address2
)
SELECT
    t._name
    select p_key from (insert into addresses values ( t.addressData1 ))
    select p_key from (insert into addresses values ( t.addressData2 ))
FROM fulldata t
```

Not sure how this can be done though, I am quite new to sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO addresses
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT addressData1
    FROM fulldata
    UNION ALL
    SELECT addressData2
    FROM fulldata
) DS
EXCEPT 
SELECT addressData -- or the name of the column in the table 
FROM addresses



insert into clients
(
    _name, 
    _address1,
    _address2
)
SELECT
    t._name
   ,A1.p_key
   ,A2.p_key
FROM fulldata t
INNER JOIN addresses A1
    ON t.addressData1 = A1.addressData -- or the name of the column in the table 
INNER JOIN addresses A2
    ON t.addressData2 = A2.addressData -- or the name of the column in the table
```

First insert the addresses, then join the table to the `fulldata` one.